# Three.js - Unexpected token '*'. import call expects exactly one argument

Tags: javascript, three.js

Unable to import three.js with import in /script.js

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*'. import call expects exactly one argument.
```

**Context**

```
/Folder/
     index.html
     index.css
     script.js
     three.module.js
     OrbitControls.js
     TransformControl.js
```

the html file (for the src value, loading these files work as expected. this is not a path error ) :

```
<script src="/script.js" ></script>
<script type="module" src="/three.module.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

After that, I'm calling the three.js file in my script.js :

```
import * as THREE from "three.module";
```

I also tried with "three.module.js" and "three.js" as well.

I got this error in the console :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*'. import call expects exactly one argument.
```

**What I have tried**

I downloaded the Three.js master folder from the three.js documentation. I
got these files from there.

1 - I have tried to add the type "module" to my script.js but I got this error :

html

```
<script type="module" src="/script.js" ></script>
```

console

```
TypeError: Module specifier does not start with "/", "./", or "../".
```

2 - I also tried to change some elements as I can find in the OrbitControls.js files (->path) :

```
import {
    EventDispatcher,
    MOUSE,
    Quaternion,
    Spherical,
    TOUCH,
    Vector2,
    Vector3
} from "../../../build/three.module.js";
```

**Conclusion**

I tried a lot of way to do it but I'm still stuck.

There is a lot of common variable in each script : three.module.js, OrbitControls.js, TransformControl.js

and when I trying to import them, there is mess.

When I'm trying to only import three.module.js, I got this error where I can't import the whole file. There is for me a kind a magic with the ES6 import module...

```
import {variable} from "/path";
```

Comment: You're right to change that script to a module, but you need to change your import from `import * as THREE from "three.module";` to `import * as THREE from "/three.module";` That's what the error is saying, that your module name `three.module` doesn't start with `/`, `./`, or `../`